# UITextView iOS8 - scroll top

Tags: uitextview, ios8, xcode6

When entering new text into my UITextView, it's scroll to the top automatically - don't know what they changed in new iOS system.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem, I solved this by writing following line in `textViewDidChange:`

```
[textView scrollRangeToVisible:[textView selectedRange]];
```

This may help you too.